# Error using saveas for plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm getting this error when I try to save a plot in MATLAB:

```
??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in ==> saveas at 64
    while ~isempty(h) &&  ~isfigure(h)

Error in ==> LongDistanceHistogram at 155
     saveas(p, ['hotspot-histograms/ddi' num2str(ddi_ctr) '.png']);
```

My plot code looks like this, and a window with the plot correctly displayed shows up when the error happens:

```
 clf;
 nums = [wrongratio truthratio];
 [counts, centers] = hist(nums,20);
 p = bar(centers, counts);
 hold on;
 title(['DDI ' num2str(ddi_ctr)]);
 xlabel('% increase in score from long-distance information');
 ylabel('Count');
 legend('Random sampling', 'Fixed M_i states', 'Location', 'Northwest');
 saveas(p, ['hotspot-histograms/ddi' num2str(ddi_ctr) '.png']);
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? This was working fine when I was doing line plots, but my attempt to change to bars seems to have broken it.

Comment: Try using `saveas` with the handle to a figure (or `gcf`) instead of the handle to the barseries; that should work.

Comment: That worked. I saw example code implying that "p=bar" was a drop-in replacement to "p=plot" but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: `p=plot` wouldn't work either, this would give you a handle to the axes, not the figure. As suggested, use `gcf` or `p = figure;` before the call to `bar`.